# Library to correct time for DST

Tags: arduino-uno, time, rtc

I am using a Uno as a data logger with a DS1307 RTC and the following libraries Time.h DS1307RTC.h

The DS1307 does not have any support for DST and neither library includes Time Zone.

Are there any libraries which adjust for DST?

---

I used the `Timezone` module to correct my times for DST.
It took a little time to sort it out, so I though I would post the steps I followed.

Customise `WriteRules` for my Timezone.
I copied rule from `WorldClock`.
NOTE also need to modify Timezone in setup(void)
Run `WriteRules.pde` to write rules to EEPROM address 100

Run `TimeRTCSet.pde` to set RTC time to UTC. 
Start Serial Monitor. 
In Terminal send time to Arduino

```
date -u +T%s > /dev/tty.usbmodemFA131
```

Run `HardwareRTC.pde` to demonstrate time display in UTC & local

I modified my sketch by including the following code:-

```
#include <Timezone.h>    //https://github.com/JChristensen/Timezone
⋯
Timezone myTZ(100);       //assumes rules stored at EEPROM address 100
TimeChangeRule *tcr;        //pointer to the time change rule, use to get TZ abbrev
time_t utc, local;
⋯
utc = now();
local = myTZ.toLocal(utc, &tcr);
```

Comment: Do you have *any* idea how ***huge*** the DST database is? Work in UTC, and perform the conversion on a bigger machine.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I am logging to FAT, and want to store file times in the usual format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Timezone library](https://github.com/JChristensen/Timezone).

Comment: The HardwareRTC appears to be what I am looking for. I will use WriteRules to store my time zone in EEPROM.